# Why is it an error to use "token_xxxx" not associated with a Customer object for payment?

Tags: stripe-payments

In the following PHP code, token_xxxx is associated with the Customer object

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_xxxx");
\Stripe\Customer::create([
  "description" => "hoge",
  "source" => "tok_amex"
]);
```

---

In the PHP code below, "token_xxxx" not associated with the Customer object is used for payment

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_xxxx');
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
  "amount" => 888,
  "currency" => "USD",
  "customer" => "cus_xxxx",
  'source' => 'tok_visa',
]);
```

・An error occurred

> Customer cus_xxxx does not have a linked source with ID tok_xxxx

Comment: In Stripe API, source is basically a saved payment method (e.g. credit card).
When you create a charge with "customer" parameter, there are two options 
1) create without `source` parameter: in this case, Customer's default source (aka default saved card) will be used. 
2) create with a "source" parameter. In this case, you will have to make sure the source provided is a card saved to the customer. 
Since `tok_visa` is just a stripe test token not saved to any customer, you could not use it together with "Customer" and that's why you see the error.

Comment: @wsw I see. I was able to understand "When I create a charge,I could not use tok_xxxx together with Customer".If you know where this is posted in the STRIPE API documentation, please let me know the link

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create#create_charge-source
See the comments the API params

Comment: I was wondering if there was a page that wrote the answer itself, but I found that I could only judge from this source parameter. It was helpful.